# Why is my background image not resizing itself? How can I solve this?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make the background image rescale with the window size, but it's not working. How come? how can I solve this?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


window = Tk()
window.geometry("1300x700")
window.title('Monopoly')
background_image = PhotoImage(file="board.png")
background_label = Label(window, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
background_label.pack()

def resizer(event):
    global bg1, resized_bg, new_bg
    bg1 = Image.open('board.png')
    resized_bg = bg1.resize((event.width, event.height))
    new_bg = PhotoImage(resized_bg)
    background_label.config(image=new_bg)

label = Label(window, text='this is a test').pack()
window.bind('<Configure>', resizer) 
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add `background_label.img = new_bg` at the end of the `resizer` function. Also change `new_bg = PhotoImage(resized_bg)` to `new_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_bg)`

Comment: It's likely due to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091

Answer (score 0):

Your `new_bg` variable is going out of scope so you need to keep it alive by doing `background_label.img = new_bg`. Also to convert a PIL image to a tkinter image you need to use `ImageTk.PhotoImage`. So change your code to:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = Tk()
window.geometry("1300x700")
window.title('Monopoly')
background_image = PhotoImage(file="board.png")
background_label = Label(window, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
background_label.pack()

def resizer(event):
    global bg1, resized_bg, new_bg
    bg1 = Image.open('board.png')
    resized_bg = bg1.resize((event.width, event.height))
    new_bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_bg) # Changed this
    background_label.img = new_bg           # Changed this
    background_label.config(image=new_bg)

label = Label(window, text='this is a test').pack()
window.bind('<Configure>', resizer) 
window.mainloop()
```

Also you shouldn't really use both `.pack` and `.place` on the same widget. You first did this: `background_label.place(...)` then this: `background_label.pack()`